# Geofence transitions service and wakelock

Tags: android, google-play-services, geofencing, android-geofence

There is [an example](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html#HandleGeofenceTransitions) how to receive geofence events like `enter` or `exit`. The example uses an ordinary IntentService. As far I known background services should use something like [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) to make sure that a service can finish its job before power off.

In my test app I follow Google example and extend my service from IntentService. And it seems to work correctly. The app writes geofence events to sqlite db without problems.

Therefore I'm curios if (a) this is only luck or (b) when using Play Services API there is no need to use wakelocks.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented similar service for my app. [Wakelock detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector&hl=ru) shows that my app has about 1500 CPU wakelocks per day for the 8 geofences. I think this means, that all required steps  already implemented in play services.

Answer (score 0):

This is not documented anywhere, thus I'd use WakefulIntentService. Example you mentioned is just an example - it does not cover all weird cases, wakelock issues including.